# VueJS - Errors interpretation in .vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started to learn VueJs and I totally got blocked by an error that prevents me from compiling my app.

My command line says:

> Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   19:46:58  error  in ./src/components/SliderHome.vue
>
> Syntax Error: Unexpected token (1:233)
>
> @ ./src/components/SliderHome.vue 11:0-366  @
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
>   @ ./src/App.vue  @ ./src/main.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

In my **sliderHome.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="wrapper" v-cloak v-bind:class="{'is-previous': isPreviousSlide, 'first-load': isFirstLoad}">
    <div class="slide-wrapper" 
         v-for="(slide, index) in slides"
         :key="slide.id, index.id"
         v-bind:class="{ active: index === currentSlide }"
         v-bind:style="{ 'z-index': (slides.length - index), 'background-image': 'url(' + slide.bgImg + ')' }">
      <div class="slide-inner">
        <div class="slide-bg-text">
          <p>{{ slide.headlineFirstLine }}</p>
          <p>{{ slide.headlineSecondLine }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-rect-filter">
          <div class="slide-rect" v-bind:style="{'border-image-source': 'url(' + slide.rectImg + ')'}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h1 class="slide-content-text"><p>{{ slide.headlineFirstLine }}</p><p>{{ slide.headlineSecondLine }}</p></h1><a class="slide-content-cta">Call To Action</a></div>
        <h2 class="slide-side-text"><span>{{ slide.sublineFirstLine }} / </span><span>{{ slide.sublineSecondLine }}</span></h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls-container">
        <button class="controls-button" 
          v-for="(slide, index) in slides"
          :key="slide.id, index.id"
          v-bind:class="{ active: index === currentSlide }"
          v-on:click="updateSlide(index)">{{ slide.headlineFirstLine }} {{ slide.headlineSecondLine }}</button>
      </div>
      <div class="pagination-container">
        <span class="pagination-item"
          v-for="(slide, index) in slides"
          :key="slide.id, index.id"
          v-bind:class="{ active: index === currentSlide }"
          v-on:click="updateSlide(index)">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

I would like to know where I need to look, or what I need to be looking for to clean this error...

Thanks in advance to any help you can bring to me.

Comment: Generally I've found unexpected syntax errors due to loading HotModuleReplacement plugin twice, once in the dev server which happens automatically and once in my `webpack.conf.js`

Comment: Is a "multiple" `key` a thing? I've never seen it. It throws the same error in a project of mine when adding another `key`.

Comment: @yuriy636 yes i'm not sure about this syntax... (Not sure it's possible) but when a don't have :key I got lot of errors from eslint... 

I will try to back in the previous version of my code where I don't have these part of code.

Edit: Nope.. this not working i'm a little "lose on the map" don't where start searching the solution.

Comment: A single `key` is fine. I was talking about having two values in one `key`. Leaving only one should work fine -- `:key="slide.id"`

Comment: I got these erros (just let me some minutes to ttry to fix these ^^) 

  3  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-trailing-spaces
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines

Comment: Nice @yuriy636 this clean out the error ! So one eslint errors stay... The last one ! (I hope ahah)

Eslint say: Arrow function should not return assignment. (no-return-assign) about 

`productRotatorSlide.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => startX = event.touches[0].pageX)`  where `(event) => endX = event.touches[0].pageX)` is the problem... ^^

Comment: @Lucju04 What does your `webpack.conf.js` or `webpack.conf.dev.js` look like and how are you running `webpack-dev-server`? Did you use `vue-cli` to init the project?

Comment: @jostrander Yes just use a vue init webpack nameproject with juste eslint, but right now a fix (I think ahah) all the errors but I get a White page I think I messed up something somewhere... I'm searching about this ^^